# Magento - How can I understand what is the error when error is not shown

Tags: php, magento

Hi there guys I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

I've made an extension which has no problem until i've created a new similar module like the old one.

When the new extension was created a problem occured on the old one.

Here on this code:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($this->getSource()->getDiscountTotal() * -1, true); ?>
```

Right now i get no result.

It is important to say that i have not made any changes on the old extension.
The strange this is that it just stopped show this value.

What options i have to find where the problem is ?
Can i get any report on this or something when it is not giving any error ?

In the new extension I also have a value similar to this one but the new value is displayed corectly.

Here is how I call the value from the new extension and it is working as intended:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($this->getSource()->getDiscountshippingTotal() * -1, true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following cod ein your index.php to enable developer mode.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set(’display_errors’, 1);
}
```

and Turn on Logging System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Log Settings -> Enabled => Yes
It will not solve your error, but will display error. :)